# WinForms - how much % of the area one rectangle covers another

Tags: c#, system.drawing, rectangles

Given two System.Drawing.Rectangle's - how to determine what % of the first rectangle's area the second rectangle covers?

For example, if the second rectangle is half-way positioned to the first one, the result should be 50%.

Comment: What do you mean by `half-way positioned`? We have 2 dimensions here: **horizontal dimension** and **vertical dimension**.

Comment: Regardless of the dimension, the result should provide how much of the first rectangle is covered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Rectangle.Intersect` method to get the `intersection` rectangle:

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(firstRect.Location, firstRect.Size);
rect.Intersect(secondRectangle);
var percentage = (rect.Width * rect.Height) * 100f/(firstRect.Width * firstRect.Height);
```